# An inequality between idempotents

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lattice-theory

Let $R$ be a unital ring. Let us denote $I_R$ by the set of all idempotent ($p^2=p$) in $R$. For given $p,q$ in $I_R$, we write $p\leq q$ if $pq=qp=p$.

Assume that  both $p\vee q$ (the supremum of $p$ and $q$) and $p\wedge q$ (the infimum of $p$ and $q$) exist in $R$ for every $p,q$ in $I_R$. we also assume that $pq=0$ if and only if $qp=0$.

Q. Let $p,q,e$ and $f$ be in $I_R$ with $pe=pf=qe=qf=0$. Can we conclud the following inequality?

$$(p+e)\wedge(q+f)\leq p\wedge q+ e\wedge f$$

Comment: Are we assuming the ring is commutative?

Comment: @benblumsmith 's observation is pertinent since otherwise $\leq$ is not a partial order relation.  In the commutative case, $p\wedge q$ is simply given by $pq$.

Comment: @ benblumsmith No, it is not commutative.

Comment: @Ruy - I don't see why noncommutativity obstructs the partial order as it was originally written. $p\leq q$, $q\leq r$ $\Rightarrow$ $pq=p$, $qr=q$; then $pr = (pq)r = p(qr) = pq = p$, so $p\leq r$. I asked about commutativity in order to figure out if $p,q\in I_R$ $\Rightarrow$ $pq\in I_R$.

Comment: Oh I guess the issue is that $pq=p$ and $qp=q$ don't imply $p=q$ in the noncommutative case... (The partial order was originally written just $p\leq q$ if $pq=p$.)

Comment: @AliBagheri - It is poor form to edit the question (especially this many times) after comments and answers make you realize you want more conditions. A better option is to accept an answer and ask a new question, linking back to this one. If you edit instead, you should at least clearly mark the edits so a reader knows what the original question was. Changing the question after it's been answered hurts the answers. For example Ruy's answer is a complete answer to the question you originally asked but a reader coming to the page now would think s/he had ignored some of the conditions.

Comment: See: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2951/altering-the-question-in-a-way-that-makes-an-answer-obsolete and http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2183/should-i-edit-this-question-or-make-a-new-question .

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, and a counter-example is $R=\mathbb R^4$, with $p=(1,1,0,0)$,
$e=(0,0,1,1)$, $q=(1,0,1,0)$ and $f=(0,1,0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks. What about if $pe=pf=qe=qf=0$?

Comment: First of all notice that, in the non-commutative case, $pq=0$ is not enough to conclude that $p+q$ is idempotent.  On the other hand, if all of your hypotheses where you say that a product is zero are replaced by orthogonality ($p\perp q \iff pq=qp=0$), then your inequality holds, and in fact it is an equality.  This is easy to prove using that $p\wedge q=pq$.

Comment: Okay.  I am working in a particular case in where $pq=0\simeq qp=0$. I  revised the question. Could you please make more clarification why in this situation $p\wedge q=pq$ ($R$ is not commutative)?

Comment: It is definitely not the case in the generality of the OP that $p\wedge q = pq$. Example: $R=M_2(\mathbb{R})$. The idempotents are $0,I$, and projections to lines. These form a ranked lattice with respect to the partial order: no two distinct projections to lines are comparable. Thus the wedge of any two such rank-1 projections is zero. But their product needn't be zero.

Comment: @benblumsmith, you are absolutely correct, sorry.  But your remark leads to another conterexample for the latest form of the question.  On $M_2(\mathbb R)$, take $p$ and $e$ to be (the projection onto) orthogonal lines,    take $q$ and $f$ to be orthogonal lines obtained by rotating $p$ and $e$ by a small angle, and then the LHS of the proposed inequality is the identity matrix, while the RHS is zero.

Comment: @benblumsmith, Observe however that $M_2(\mathbb R)$ does not satisfy the condition added to the latest form of the question according to which $pq=0$ implies that $qp=0$.

Comment: @Ruy - I had actually considered that example and was going to put it in an answer, but then I thought (even before this last edit) that it didn't meet the conditions $pf=qe=0$.

Comment: @AliBagheri , I am having a hard time finding an example of a non-commutative situation in which $pq=0\iff qp=0$, for any pair of projections $p$ and $q$.  By any chance, did your question arise in a context were such an example can be given?

Comment: @benblumsmith, curiously,  the condition $pq=0\Rightarrow qp=0$, guarantees that $p=pq\Rightarrow p=qp$.  Here is why:
assuming that $p=pq$,  one has that $r:=qp$ is a projection.  Since one clearly has $r(1-p)=0$, then the hypothesis
gives $(1-p)r=0$, which translates into $qp=pqp$, whence $qp=p$. QED

Comment: @Ruy - you're right, since $pq=p \Rightarrow p(q-1)=0 \Rightarrow (q-1)p=0 \Rightarrow qp = p$, but I'm not sure why $r$ is a projection.

Comment: @benblumsmith, this is a nice argument, much shorter than the one I gave.  In any case, in my argument, $r$ is an idempotent (i.e. a projection) because $r^2=qpqp = q(pq)p =   qpp = qp = r$.

Comment: @Ruy - Thank you. (I had forgotten that $p$ was a projection! So I didn't see why $qpp=qp$.)